# Can I store my data outside of /home?

Tags: 15.10, directory

I have moved my /home folder to a separate partition of my Ubuntu 15.10 because of space issues.

That has freed up enough space that I'd like to sync my Dropbox folder, but I can't fit it in home. I have ample space in the [not sure what to call this] installation partition (the root filesystem?).

Is there a persistent and private folder there that I could use to create a "data" folder?

cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put your files in a /home is just a convention. You can store your files wherever you want. If you want to use some space in root make a directory there and set the permissions that match the permissions of your other files in your home directory. You can even make a symbolic link to your home directory. For instance:

```
sudo mkdir /mydata
sudo chown myusername:myusername /mydata
ln -s /mydata ~/mydata
```

Put whatever you want in that folder. You will have a folder mydata in your home directory which will point to the mydata folder in the root. Change the name mydata to whatever you like. In the last command `ln` you don't need to use the same name twice. You can also do it like this

```
ln -s /mydata ~/linktomydata
```

The `~` represents your home directory. So you can also write

```
ln -s /mydata /home/<username>/linktomydata
```

where you put your username instead of `<username>`.